# Factory Method: Prevent a class from Direct Instancing

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I have a `Factory Method` to instance a class. Is there a way to prevent this class from direct instancing?

The only option I see is to use an argument passed into the `__construct()`, but that's not something I'm looking for.

On the other hand, making the `__construct()` private would be ideal, but I don't want `MyClass` to extend the `Factory` without actual need.

What do you guys think?

**Factory Method:**

```
class Factory
{
    public static function instance()
    {
        return new MyClass(true);
    }
}
```

**MyClass:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct($isFactory = false)
    {
        if (!$isFactory) {
            throw new Exception('Use Factory::instance() to create an object');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First; the definition of MyClass should be revisited:  **class MyClass(){** should read **class MyClass{** without the **()** after the class MyClass... ;-)

Comment: @Poiz thanks, didn't notice this typo. Corrected now.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @PeeHaa in my case `Factory` determines a concrete class, loads it and and confirms its type. Direct instance (by somebody who doesn't read docs) of a class without its type confirmed might lead to unexpected results so I want to avoid that.

Comment: @PeeHaa basically, making the component foolproof

Comment: So you are also going to have to use the factory to test the class?

Comment: Also people can extend your class and ignore your constructor.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm simply calling `instanceof` to confirm the object the factory just created is of a correct type. The goal is to allow creating new classes the factory instances by less experienced developers, so I'm tying to do all I can to foolproof the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hacks to do that:

- abusing inheritance to use a `protected` constructor
- putting the factory method inside the class so that it can call the private constructor, which is actually not a hack. But then why not using the constructor in the first place?
- using reflection to access the private constructor

I'm not promoting anything of that. What I personally do is documenting the API with things like [`@internal`](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html) and leave it to the client following that contract.

Comment: I agree. It's hard to fix stupid. At some point you just have to let it go.

Comment: Thanks Markus, completely agree with you about hacks.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, your code should have read something like this:

**THE FACTORY**

```
    <?php
    class Factory {

        public static function instance(){
            return new MyClass(true); //HERE YOU ARE INSTANTIATING
        }
    }
```

**THE CLASS TO BE INSTANTIATED VIA THE FACTORY**

```
     <?php
    //NOT MyClass() <--- YOU ARE DEFINING.... NOT INSTANTIATING...
    class MyClass {

        public function __construct($isFactory = false) {
            if (!$isFactory) {
                throw new Exception('Use Factory::instance() to create an object');
            }
        }

        //...MORE METHODS
    }
```

Could you try this instead?

```
    <?php
        class Factory
        {
            private static $FACTORY_GUARANTOR;      //ONLY SET DURING INSTANTIATION
            public static function instance($type) {
                if (class_exists($type)) {
                    self::$FACTORY_GUARANTOR = 1;
                    $instance = new $type();
                    self::$FACTORY_GUARANTOR = null;
                    return $instance;
                }
                else {
                    throw new Exception("Class not found...");
                }
            }

            //YOU CAN GET $FACTORYGUARANTOR EXTERNALLY BUT NEVER SET IT;
            public static function getGuarantor(){
                return self::$FACTORY_GUARANTOR;
            }
        }



        class MyClass {
            protected $property1;
            protected $property3;
            protected $property2;

            public function __construct() {
                // IF SOMEONE TRIES TO INSTANTIATE THE CLASS OUTSIDE OF THE FACTORY... BLOW A WHISTLE
                if(!Factory::getGuarantor()){
                    throw new Exception('Use Factory::instance() to create an object');
                }
                // IF THE PROGRAM MADE IT TO THIS POINT;
                // JUST INSTANTIATE THE CLASS BECAUSE MOST LIKELY IT IS COMING FROM THE FACTORY
                var_dump($this); // A LITTLE CONFIRMATION....
            }

            //...MORE METHODS
        }

        // TRY IT OUT:
        /*INSTANCE A: RIGHT*/   $theClass   = Factory::instance("MyClass"); //INSTANTIATES THE CLASS
        /*INSTANCE B: WRONG*/   $theClass   = new MyClass();                //THROWS AN EXCEPTION
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. However, that's not the question I'm asking.

Comment: I updated the code... you may want to take a look at it... (if you will) ;-)

Comment: This will also not work. Consider after `$theClass   = Factory::instance("MyClass");` the line `$theClass   = new MyClass();` will work!

Comment: @Ed Heal       You should just try the code yourself.... and read the comments. The 2 Types of Instantiations are just examples to illustrate which works and which not. To try it out... you must comment-out 1 of the instantiations to see the results... if you run it like that, it wont work... I will also add this point above the instantiations....

Comment: @Poiz that's a nice trick to solve the issue, thanks. However, @EdHeal has a point. `Factory::$FACTORY_GUARANTOR` needs to be reset once an instance is created. That's not a singleton, so we need to consider multiple calls of the `Factory::instance()`.

Comment: @Sergey Mitroshin     .... based on the older Code, He is right... but check the updated one...

Comment: Perhaps using [class implements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) would be useful as well.

Comment: @Ed Heal       Sure... but anyways, did you try now the update code? What was your result?

Comment: @Poiz yup, the updated one looks good. Anyway, it's not a question of a concrete implementation, but rather the idea. Thank you, I appreciate your response, just want to see if someone else would offer any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define your base class as `abstract`. The `abstract` classes cannot be directly instanced, so you will have to redefine their abstract members in the inherited classes:

```
abstract class Factory
{
    abstract public function foo();
}

class InheritedClass extends Factory
{
    public function foo()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

// $obj1 = new Factory(); // Will produce an error
$obj1 = new InheritedClass(); // Will be executed successfully
```

You can read more for the `abstract` classes here: [PHP: Class Abstraction - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way is to use ReflectionClass:

```
class MyClass
{    
    public const FRIEND_CLASSES = [Factory::class];

    protected function __construct() {}
}

trait Constructor
{
    protected function createObject(string $className, array $args = [])
    {
        if (!in_array(static::class, $className::FRIEND_CLASSES)) {
            throw new \Exception("Call to private or protected {$className}::__construct() from invalid context");
        }
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
        $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();
        $constructor->setAccessible(true);
        $object = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        $constructor->invokeArgs($object, $args);
        return $object;
    }
}

class Factory
{
    use Constructor;

    public function MyClass(): MyClass
    {
        return $this->createObject(MyClass::class);
    }
}
```

In constant FRIEND_CLASSES you can define in which classes the class can be instanced.

trait is used because this functionality can be used in different factories that are not related.

If you need to put parameters into constructor of the class, put them as second parameter of createObject.

Details I described in the article "[Forbidding of creating objects outside factory in PHP](https://medium.com/@marenkov/forbidding-of-creating-objects-outside-factory-in-php-7173d7be6cb4)"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31351808)